# Mule 4 : Property Files : is it advisable to read items from property files repeatedly for every request made to Mule 4 app?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Scenario :
In properties file we have defined few items say 5 as below :

```
item_1=value1
item_2=value2
item_3=value3
item_4=value4
item_5=value5
```

I need to read these properties to form a request for a particular environment[dev,qa]. So I kept them in properties file.
So the process seems as follows :

1. My flow started due to an event
2. The dataweave script reads these properties and forms the request
3. The HTTP requester executes the request

For every single request, I have to repeat steps 1 to 3, where in step 2 property file is read.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: It’s fine unless you have a performance issue.  Simple, straightforward, easy to maintain. Until you get to the point where you need to performance tune it to do hundreds or thousands of transactions per second, you’re probably good with that approach.

Comment: Assuming the performance is an issue, what should be the approach to optimizing it? Can we do something like a static block in Java code in Mule flows as well?

Comment: Don’t worry about optimizing until you performance test and profile it. Then you’ll see whether there is a performance problem and profiling will tell you where.  You’ll almost certainly find bigger performance problems in other parts of the code.

Comment: Do you have a reason to read properties using DataWeave instead of a confirmation properties? Please share an example of the XML so we can understand more in detail.

Comment: @BibekKr.Bazaz - I'm going to assume you're using a configuration provider rather than actually parsing the file with dataweave. There aren't going to be any truly perceptible ways to improve the efficiency on that, and the developer/ops experience gains almost assuredly outweigh any performance gains.

Comment: Without more details about how the flow actually reads the properties -from where- it is not possible to provide an answer.

Comment: @aled The mule flow contains a HTTP listener. After the HTTP listener it has a Transform message that contains my dataweave code where i am reading the properties using the p() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the comments I understand that the properties are defined with normal mule methods and are just used from DataWeave with the p() function.That's perfectly fine usage. Unless you have an issue there nothing that needs to be changed.